# trac SmtpLdapEmailSender to field is empty

Tags: ldap, trac

I am getting the following problem with this plugin. using trac 0.12.5 on centos 5. the following log is from a comment. user responding is sharif.uddin, user created is jason. and user i am trying to cc to is ramy.

```
   Trac[paradox:env] INFO: Reloading environment due to configuration change
Trac[paradox:env] INFO: -------------------------------- environment startup [Trac 0.12.5] --------------------------------
Trac[paradox:api] INFO: Synchronized '(default)' repository in 0.01 seconds
Trac[paradox:api] INFO: Synchronized '(default)' repository in 0.00 seconds
Trac[paradox:env] INFO: Reloading environment due to configuration change
Trac[paradox:env] INFO: -------------------------------- environment startup [Trac 0.12.5] --------------------------------
Trac[paradox:api] INFO: Synchronized '(default)' repository in 0.06 seconds
Trac[paradox:SmtpLdapEmailSender] INFO: Binding to LDAP as cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
Trac[paradox:SmtpLdapEmailSender] INFO: Updating list of recipients
Trac[paradox:SmtpLdapEmailSender] WARNING: Searching LDAP server ldap://echo.uk.domain.com for user jasona@DOMAIN.COM
Trac[paradox:SmtpLdapEmailSender] WARNING: Found e-mail address: Jason.Aftalion@domain.com
Trac[paradox:SmtpLdapEmailSender] WARNING: Searching LDAP server ldap://echo.uk.domain.com for user sharifu@DOMAIN.COM
Trac[paradox:SmtpLdapEmailSender] WARNING: Found e-mail address: Sharif.Uddin@domain.com
Trac[paradox:SmtpLdapEmailSender] WARNING: Searching LDAP server ldap://echo.uk.domain.com for user Ramy.Mahmoud@domain.com
Trac[paradox:notification] INFO: Sending notification through SMTP at hero.uk.domain.com:25 to ['Jason.Aftalion@domain.com', 'Sharif.Uddin@domain.com', u'Ramy.Mahmoud@domain.com', 'support@domain.com']
Trac[paradox:api] INFO: Synchronized '(default)' repository in 0.01 seconds
Trac[paradox:api] INFO: Synchronized '(default)' repository in 0.00 seconds
```

I have the following code for the plugin in `site-packages`

```
class SmtpLdapEmailSender(SmtpEmailSender):

    implements(IEmailSender)

    email_ldap_serveruri = Option('notification', 'email_ldap_serveruri', '',
                               """AD LDAP Server to use for looking up e-mail addresses""")
    email_ldap_port = IntOption('notification', 'email_ldap_port', 389, """AD LDAP Server port""")
    email_ldap_binddn = Option('notification', 'email_ldap_binddn', '',
                               """Bind DN for LDAP lookup. If not given, Kerberos auth will be used for current user""")
    email_ldap_bindpw = Option('notification', 'email_ldap_bindpw', '', """Password for non-kerberos auth""")
    email_ldap_basedn = Option('notification', 'email_ldap_basedn', '', """Base DN to use for LDAP searches""")

    email_attr = 'mail'

    def __init__(self):
        self.log.warn("Initialising LDAP object with URI: ", self.email_ldap_serveruri)
        self.ldap_conn=ldap.initialize(self.email_ldap_serveruri)



    def send(self, from_addr, recipients, message):
        #self.log.warn(recipients)
        if self.email_ldap_binddn != None:
            self.log.info("Binding to LDAP as " + self.email_ldap_binddn)
            self.ldap_conn.bind_s(self.email_ldap_binddn, self.email_ldap_bindpw, ldap.AUTH_SIMPLE)
        else:
            self.log.info("Binding to LDAP with Kerberos")
            self.ldap_conn.bind_s()

        #Iterate through recipients, checking for correct e-mail addresses in LDAP
        #Output in ldapRecipients
        self.log.info("Updating list of recipients")
        new_recipients = []

        def isset(variable):
            return variable in locals() or variable in globals()        

        for i, addr in enumerate(recipients):
            self.log.warn("Searching LDAP server %s for user %s", self.email_ldap_serveruri, addr)
            search_string = 'userPrincipalName=' + addr
            result = self.ldap_conn.search_s(self.email_ldap_basedn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, search_string, [self.email_attr])

            #result is formatted as a string (result) in a list of [attr values], in a dictionary of {attr_name=>attr_values}
            #in a tuple of (DN, Entry), within a list of results. So result for principle name jasona@domain.com would be
            #[('CN=Jason Aftalion,OU=TechSupport,OU=Woking,OU=Sites,DC=domain,DC=com', {'mail': ['Jason.Aftalion@domain.com']})]
            #self.log.error(addr)

            if len(result) > 0:
                if result[0][1][self.email_attr][0]:                    
                    self.log.warn("Found e-mail address: " + result[0][1][self.email_attr][0])
                    new_recipients.append(result[0][1][self.email_attr][0])
                else:
                    self.log.warn("Could not find e-mail address")
                    new_recipients.append(addr)
            else:
                new_recipients.append(addr)

        new_recipients.append("support@domain.com")
        #self.log.error(new_recipients)

        return super(SmtpLdapEmailSender,self).send(from_addr, new_recipients, message)
```

Also when the email gets sent out there is no one on the `to` address. I think i need to add the `u` before the quites open on the email if you see the log line `Trac[paradox:notification] INFO: Sending notification through SMTP at hero.uk.domain.com:25 to ['Jason.Aftalion@domian.com', 'Sharif.Uddin@domian.com', u'Ramy.Mahmoud@domain.com']` . ramy is the only one that appears in the email as it is placed on the cc section of the ini file.

**UPDATE**

```
[root@hero plugins]# easy_install http://trac-hacks.org/svn/announcerplugin/trunk
Downloading http://trac-hacks.org/svn/announcerplugin/trunk
Doing subversion checkout from http://trac-hacks.org/svn/announcerplugin/trunk to /tmp/easy_install-hkATrd/trunk
Processing trunk
Running setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-hkATrd/trunk/egg-dist-tmp-dGEGqu
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/announcer/opt/bitten/announce.py", line 71
    yield
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
TracAnnouncer 1.0dev-r12503 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/TracAnnouncer-1.0dev_r12503-py2.4.egg
Processing dependencies for TracAnnouncer==1.0dev-r12503
Finished processing dependencies for TracAnnouncer==1.0dev-r12503
```

**UPDATE 2**

It installed successfully

```
 easy_install http://trac-hacks.org/svn/announcerplugin/trunk
Downloading http://trac-hacks.org/svn/announcerplugin/trunk
Doing subversion checkout from http://trac-hacks.org/svn/announcerplugin/trunk to /tmp/easy_install-AGCmXH/trunk
Processing trunk
Running setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-AGCmXH/trunk/egg-dist-tmp-6tmNSt
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Removing TracAnnouncer 1.0dev-r12503 from easy-install.pth file
Adding TracAnnouncer 1.0dev-r13963 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/TracAnnouncer-1.0dev_r13963-py2.4.egg
Processing dependencies for TracAnnouncer==1.0dev-r13963
Finished processing dependencies for TracAnnouncer==1.0dev-r13963
```

I get following in log file now. I cannot install python 2.7

```
Trac[paradox:env] INFO: -------------------------------- environment startup [Trac 0.12.5] --------------------------------
Trac[paradox:loader] ERROR: Skipping "announcer.email_decorators = announcer.email_decorators": 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/Trac-0.12.5-py2.4.egg/trac/loader.py", line 68, in _load_eggs
    entry.load(require=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/announcer/email_decorators.py", line 7, in ?
ImportError: No module named utils
Trac[paradox:api] INFO: Synchronized '(default)' repository in 0.66 seconds
```

local ini file

```
 cat /data/intranet/html/trac/paradox/conf/trac.ini
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

[changeset]
max_diff_files = 0

[components]
acct_mgr.admin.accountmanageradminpanel = disabled
acct_mgr.api.accountmanager = disabled
acct_mgr.db.sessionstore = disabled
acct_mgr.guard.accountguard = disabled
acct_mgr.macros.accountmanagerwikimacros = disabled
acct_mgr.notification.accountchangelistener = disabled
acct_mgr.notification.accountchangenotificationadminpanel = disabled
acct_mgr.register.emailcheck = disabled
acct_mgr.register.emailverificationmodule = disabled
advancedworkflow.controller.ticketworkflowopownercomponent = disabled
advancedworkflow.controller.ticketworkflowopownerfield = disabled
advancedworkflow.controller.ticketworkflowopownerprevious = disabled
advancedworkflow.controller.ticketworkflowopresetmilestone = disabled
advancedworkflow.controller.ticketworkflowoprunexternal = disabled
advancedworkflow.controller.ticketworkflowopstatusprevious = disabled
advancedworkflow.controller.ticketworkflowoptriage = disabled
advancedworkflow.controller.ticketworkflowopxref = disabled
announcer.api.announcementsystem = enabled
announcer.api.subscriptionresolver = enabled
announcer.distributors.mail.emaildistributor = enabled
announcer.distributors.mail.sendmailemailsender = enabled
announcer.distributors.mail.smtpemailsender = enabled
announcer.email_decorators.announceremaildecorator = enabled
announcer.email_decorators.staticemaildecorator = enabled
announcer.email_decorators.threadingemaildecorator = enabled
announcer.email_decorators.ticketaddlheaderemaildecorator = enabled
announcer.email_decorators.ticketsubjectemaildecorator = enabled
announcer.email_decorators.wikisubjectemaildecorator = enabled
announcer.filters.defaultpermissionfilter = enabled
announcer.formatters.ticketformatter = enabled
announcer.formatters.wikiformatter = enabled
announcer.opt.subscribers.allticketsubscriber = enabled
announcer.opt.subscribers.generalwikisubscriber = enabled
announcer.opt.subscribers.joinablegroupsubscriber = enabled
announcer.opt.subscribers.ticketcomponentownersubscriber = enabled
announcer.opt.subscribers.ticketcomponentsubscriber = enabled
announcer.opt.subscribers.ticketcustomfieldsubscriber = enabled
announcer.opt.subscribers.userchangesubscriber = enabled
announcer.opt.subscribers.watchsubscriber = enabled
announcer.pref.announcerpreferences = enabled
announcer.pref.subscriptionmanagementpanel = enabled
announcer.producers.attachmentchangeproducer = enabled
announcer.producers.ticketchangeproducer = enabled
announcer.producers.wikichangeproducer = enabled
announcer.resolvers.defaultdomainemailresolver = enabled
announcer.resolvers.sessionemailresolver = enabled
announcer.resolvers.specifiedemailresolver = enabled
announcer.resolvers.specifiedxmppresolver = enabled
announcer.subscribers.carboncopysubscriber = enabled
announcer.subscribers.ticketownersubscriber = enabled
announcer.subscribers.ticketreportersubscriber = enabled
announcer.subscribers.ticketupdatersubscriber = enabled
spectrum.smtpldapemailsender.smtpldapemailsender = enabled
tracopt.mimeview.php.phprenderer = enabled

[header_logo]
alt = 
link = http://intranet/trac/paradox/
src = common/trac_banner.png

[inherit]
file = /usr/share/trac/conf/trac.ini

[logging]
log_level = INFO
log_type = file

[project]
descr = Paradox replacement
name = Paradox
url = http://intranet/sidb

[ticket]
default_component = other
default_milestone = create/update project
default_version = v12

[ticket-workflow]
accept = new -> assigned
accept.operations = set_owner_to_self
accept.permissions = TICKET_MODIFY
leave = * -> *
leave.default = 1
leave.operations = leave_status
reassign = new,assigned,reopened -> new
reassign.operations = set_owner
reassign.permissions = TICKET_MODIFY
reopen = closed -> reopened
reopen.operations = del_resolution
reopen.permissions = TICKET_CREATE
resolve = new,assigned,reopened -> closed
resolve.operations = set_resolution
resolve.permissions = TICKET_MODIFY

[trac]
base_url = http://intranet/trac/paradox/
check_auth_ip = true
metanav = login,logout,settings,help,about
repository_dir = /data/subversion/paradox


[notification]
smtp_always_cc = Ramy.Mahmoud@domain.com

[announcer] 
use_public_cc = true
```

global ini file

```
cat ../conf/trac.ini 
[announcer]
use_public_cc = true
#admit_domains =
#always_notify_component_owner = true
#always_notify_owner = true
#always_notify_reporter = true
#always_notify_updater = true
#default_email_format = text/html
#email_address_resolvers = SpecifiedEmailResolver, SessionEmailResolver
#ignore_domains =
#mime_encoding = base64
#smtp_always_bcc =
#smtp_always_cc =
#smtp_default_domain =
#smtp_enabled = true
#smtp_from = trac-no-reply@domain.com
#smtp_from_name = Trac
#smtp_password =
#smtp_port = 25
#smtp_replyto = no-reply@domain.com
#smtp_server = hero
#smtp_subject_prefix = __default__
#smtp_timeout = 30
#smtp_user =
#t#icket_email_header_fields = owner, reporter, milestone, component, priority, severity.
#ticket_email_subject = Ticket #${ticket.id}: ${ticket['summary']}.
#ticket_subject_template = $prefix $ticket.id: $summary
#use_public_cc = false
#use_short_addr = false
#use_tls = false
#email_enabled = true

[notification]
always_notify_owner = false
always_notify_reporter = true
always_notify_updater = true
#mime_encoding = base64
#smtp_always_cc = sharifu@domain.com
#smtp_default_domain = domain.com
smtp_enabled = true
smtp_from = trac@domain.com
smtp_password =
smtp_port = 25
smtp_replyto = no-reply@domain.com
smtp_server = hero.uk.domain.com
smtp_subject_prefix = __default__
smtp_user =
use_public_cc = false
use_short_addr = false
use_tls = false
#ignore_domains = domain.com

email_sender=SmtpLdapEmailSender
email_ldap_serveruri = ldap://echo.uk.domain.com
email_ldap_port = 389
email_ldap_basedn = ou=Sites,dc=domain,dc=com
email_ldap_binddn = cn=Administrator,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=com
email_ldap_bindpw = ****

[ldap]
enable = true
global_perms = true
host = echo
basedn = dc=domain,dc=com
user_rdn = ou=sites
group_rdn = cn=users
store_bind = true
bind_user = cn=Administrator,cn=users,dc=domain,dc=com
bind_passwd = ****



[trac]
base_url = http://intranet/trac/
#permission_store = LdapPermissionStore


[logging]
log_format = Trac[$(basename)s:$(module)s] $(levelname)s: $(message)s
log_type = syslog
log_level = WARN



[components]
webadmin.* = enabled
#ldapauth.* = enabled
#ldapplugin.* = enabled
#ldapplugin.api.ldappermissiongroupprovider = enabled
#ldapplugin.api.ldappermissionstore = disabled
ticketdelete.* = enabled
tracopt.ticket.deleter = enabled
tracwysiwyg.* = enabled
advancedworkflow.* = enabled
#tickettemplate.* = enabled

tracopt.ticket.commit_updater.committicketreferencemacro = enabled
tracopt.ticket.commit_updater.committicketupdater = enabled
ticketchangesets.* = enabled
ticketlog.* = enabled

#announcer.* = enabled
#announcer.api.announcementsystem = enabled
#announcer.distributors.mail.emaildistributor = enabled
#announcer.formatters.ticket.ticketformatter = enabled
#announcer.formatters.wiki.wikiformatter = enabled
#announcer.pref.announcerpreferences = enabled
#announcer.producers.attachment.attachmentchangeproducer = enabled
#announcer.producers.ticket.ticketchangeproducer = enabled
#announcer.producers.wiki.wikichangeproducer = enabled
#announcer.resolvers.sessionemail.sessionemailresolver = enabled
#announcer.subscribers.ticket_compat.carboncopysubscriber = enabled
#announcer.subscribers.ticket_compat.legacyticketsubscriber = enabled
#announcer.subscribers.ticket_components.ticketcomponentsubscriber = enabled
#announcer.subscribers.ticket_custom.ticketcustomfieldsubscriber = enabled
#announcer.subscribers.watch_users.userchangesubscriber = enabled
#announcer.subscribers.watchers.watchsubscriber = enabled

#[tickettemplate]
#field_list = summary, description, reporter, owner, priority, cc, milestone, component, version, type
#enable_custom = true

[ticket-changesets]
check_perms = true
collapsed = false
commands.close = close closed closes fix fixed fixes
commands.refs = addresses re references refs see
compact = true
envelope = 
hide_when_none = false
notify = true
resolution = fixed
ticket_comments = true

[ticket]
commit_ticket_update_envelope = []
commit_ticket_update_commands.close =
commit_ticket_update_commands.refs = <ALL>
commit_ticket_update_check_perms = true
commit_ticket_update_notify = true

[ticketlog]
; optional: custom your log message pattern
log_pattern = \s*#%s\s+.*
; optional: set log message's max length, default is no limit
log_message_maxlength = 100
```

When i leave a comment i see the following extra bit in log file

```
Trac[paradox:api] ERROR: AnnouncementSystem failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/announcer/api.py", line 560, in _real_send
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/announcer/api.py", line 311, in subscriptions
TypeError: itemgetter expected 1 arguments, got 4
```

**QUESTION 2**

Do emails notification not get sent out when adding attachments? i found the following in the log...

```
Trac[paradox:api] INFO: Synchronized '(default)' repository in 0.01 seconds
Trac[paradox:attachment] INFO: New attachment: ticket:48: RE Conversation with Ringo Au.msg by sharifu@DOMAIN.COM
Trac[paradox:api] ERROR: AnnouncementSystem failed.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/announcer/api.py", line 560, in _real_send
  File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/announcer/api.py", line 311, in subscriptions
TypeError: itemgetter expected 1 arguments, got 4
```

Comment: Your plugins appears to utilize the [AnnouncerPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/AnnouncerPlugin) API. Which version of AnnouncerPlugin are you using? It does not appear that AnnouncerPlugin supports having a user in the `To` field. It appears the feature you are asking for has been requested in [#11250](http://trac-hacks.org/ticket/11250).Have you tried `[announcer]` `use_public_cc = true`? That should cause the list of users to be visible in the CC field rather than putting them in the BCC field.

Comment: `TracAnnouncer 1.0dev-r12503` i have just tried adding that in the global ini file. did not work.

Comment: see update, tried to run install

Comment: I'm not sure how well the AnnouncerPlugin trunk will work with Python 2.4. I pushed a fix for the issue you encountered just now: [r13963](http://trac-hacks.org/changeset/13963).

Comment: see update 2, i have pasted the log and ini files

Comment: Looking at the history on trac-hacks and SO, I see that we've discussed this before. You'll need the patch in [#9106](http://trac-hacks.org/ticket/9106). We'll see about getting that applied to the trunk.

Comment: I have added another question, i think its related

Comment: The error when sending out attachments is due to the Python 2.4 compatibility issue. Please install the latest version of the trunk and you should find that it's fixed (previously mentioned patch has been applied). Notifications will be sent when attachments are added if you are subscribed to the ticket.

Comment: There are no errors in log file but the To section is still blank